How does the BIOS teletype routine work?
I am writing an OS. I am not a computer scientist, I am a physicist, so my understanding of computing is limited enough that I don't yet know how to ask the right questions. I am looking for either a response to the following or guidance towards finding the right question to ask:
I am working with x86. There is an instruction I want to understand fully.
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV AL, 'A'
INT 0x10

When I assemble, this becomes B4 0E B0 41 CD 10 in hexadecimal. By looking at an opcode table, I can see that B4 moves 0E to registry AH, B0 moves ASCII value 41 to registry AL, and CD 10 is an interrupt which results in the character "A" being printed to the screen.
The reference I'm studying explains that

The specific routine we want is the BIOS scrolling teletype routine,
which will print a single character on the screen and advance the
cursor, ready for the next character. There is a whole list of BIOS
routines published that show you which interrupt to use and how to set
the registers prior to the interrupt. Here, we need interrupt 0x10 and
to set ah to 0x0e (to indicate tele-type mode) and al to the ASCII
code of the character we wish to print.

This all leaves me with some questions:

How does this BIOS routine work?
Where and how is the ASCII code stored in memory?
How does this interrupt result in a character being printed?


We're not a coding site, and questions about code or implementation are normally off-topic here.  However, this question seems likely to be too broad for anywhere on Stack Exchange, as our rule is to ask one question per post.  I suggest you start by doing some research on BIOS and how it works, and then see if you can ask a narrower question.  They might be on-topic on Stack Overflow.  P.S. registry -> register

Possibly relevant: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1700/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29848/755, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116629/9812, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/135961/755
